# Simulating a string with a custom python object

Tags: python, string, lazy-evaluation

I would like to simulate a string with a custom python objet in a way the test code below should work :

```
import os
class A(str):
    path=""

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.path
    def __str__(self):
        return self.path

a=A()
a.path = "myfile"

print os.path.join('mydir',a)
```

I was expecting

```
mydir/myfile
```

But I got only

```
mydir/
```

How to code my class to simulate a string ?

Answer (score 1):

You might try using `UserString.UserString` instead of directly subclassing string:

```
import os
from UserString import UserString

class A(UserString):

    def __init__(self, initial=''):
        self.data = initial

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self.data

    @path.setter
    def path(self, value):
        self.data = value

a=A()
a.path = "myfile"

print(os.path.join('mydir',a))
```

Edit: I wrote the answer using python3's `collection.UserString`, then found that it was backported to python2 as well.